# Re-setup git and re-connect to remote repository

Tags: git, github

I re-setup my entire os (debian 8), installed git and cloned my dotfiles from a remote repository to get my initial settings back and working again.

**My question is:** How do I re-setup git to track the dotfiles again and how do I re-connect to the remote repository?

`git status` appears to be showing all the files in my home directory, so `.gitignore` doesn't seem to work..

Do I have to `git init` again? Or just commit the files I want to track. How do I get my `.gitignore` to work?

I'm a lost noob.. :(

Comment: if you have already used git in your files then there is no need to do `git init` again. So to track git files try `git add file-name` and check the files tracked using `git status` and then do `git commit` and `git push` to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zachi: Thanks for the quick response!

I deleted all the dotfiles and the `.git` directory and did `git clone` again since there was obviously some kinky voodoo stuff going on (git status showing the whole directory despite `.gitignore` being in place etc.)

**Solution (see zachi):** create `.gitignore`, `git add <files>`, `git status`, `git commit`, `git push`!

Thanks and sorry for bothering!